# Orientation issue with iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, orientation

I have an iPhone application who need to run on iOS 7 and iOS 8. It's a full Portrait Application, except for the video player who is displayed thanks to a presented ViewController.

When I start the application from the landscape mode on an iPhone 6 or 6 Plus, It will cause to destroy the HomeView. All the orientation are supported in the project because of the video player (I know I can avoid the problem by removing the landscape support but my video player won't be displayed properly).

So the question is : How can I do to start my application from landscape mode without break the HomeView (so in a nice portrait mode) but at the same time still have my video player properly displayed in landscape mode ?

PS : I can't post screenshots, so when I say "destroy", just imagine the view with not well positioned and scaled elements.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do to start my application from landscape mode without break the HomeView (so in a nice portrait mode) but at the same time still have my video player properly displayed in landscape mode ?

How the application is oriented on launch depends on the order in which the supported orientations are listed in the *Info.plist* file. Just make sure that Portrait comes first.

How the home view can be oriented depends on the root view controller's implementation of `supportedInterfaceOrientation`. Make sure that it returns UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait.

Answer (score 0):

1. In **Info.plist** set device orientation just to `Portrait`
2. In **AppDelegate** add -

   ```
   - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
   {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
   }
   ```